# wordpress onepage template add jQuery smooth scroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, smooth-scrolling

i have create a one page template in wordpress with the below code.

```
<?php get_header();

    // define how pages will display
    $args = array(
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order', //post_title
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'exclude' => '',
        'child_of' => 2,
        'parent' => -1,
        'exclude_tree' => '',
        'number' => '',
        'offset' => 0,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $pages = get_pages($args);
//start loop
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
    $slug = $page_data->post_name;
?>

<main role="main">
    <!-- section -->
    <section>

        <div class='<?php echo "$slug" ?>'>
            <h1><?php echo "$title" ?></h1>
                <?php echo "$content" ?>
        </div>



    </section><!-- /section -->
</main>

<?php
}
get_footer();
?>
```

Now I want to create the menu and scroll it with jQuery smooth.
Someone can tell me how can do to make it?
thank you

Comment: Create a menu from Wordpress backend and use it in this template. Else write html nav menu in this file after header and see if it works as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi, This means that I have to remove the menu from the template header?..and create it in this template?